# How can I change "month" to "second" without crashing my browser?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to generate a line chart. I want to visualise the data by month, seconds, minutes etc.(change the xAxis accordingly) When I change "month" to "second" the browser crashes.. Almost anything but month works correctly

```
xAxes: [{
          fontColor: 'orange',
          type: 'time',
          distribution: 'linear',
            time: {
                   unit: 'month',
                   displayFormats: {
                       second: 'h:mm:ss a'
                   }
 },
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJmrpw

Comment: Chart.js documentations:

Time Units
The following time measurements are supported. The names can be passed as strings to the time.unit config option to force a certain unit.

millisecond
second
minute
hour
day
week
month
quarter
year

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: That's an awful lot of seconds you're asking it to consider

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks for your reply! Yes my dataset isn't the best to visualise by seconds. I was to focused in "options" and "configuration" that I haven' t pay attention to the most important..!